# Retrieving Manager for a list of users from Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We use .NET and the latest Microsoft.Graph NuGet SDK version 5.16 to retrieve members of an Azure Active Directory group. We need to return back a list of users including information about each user's manager (manager's name).

Our code looks like this:

```
foreach (var groupMember in groupMembers.Value)
{
    if (groupMember is User)
    {
        var u = (User)groupMember;
        var manager = await graphClient.Users[u.Id].Manager.GetAsync();
        u.Manager = manager;
    }
}
```

The issue is performance. We have a lot of users in that particular group, and after several dozens of users are added, the line ***u.Manager = manager*** slows down to a crawl. I believe this is because the Microsoft.Graph.Models.User.Manager property is backed up by IBackingStore implementation that does a lot of change tracking. Anyways, that's Microsoft's code that we don't control.

Do you know of a way to work around this issue aside from wrapping the User type into a POCO? Is there a way to retrieve the Manager name for a list of users? Is there a way to configure Graph SDK to suppress change tracking?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you get group members but when you return only users which are members of the group, you can expand `manager` relationship and configure only a `displayName` of a manager to be returned.

```
var groupMembers = await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"]
                           .Members
                           .GraphUser
                           .GetAsync((requestConf) =>
{
    requestConf.QueryParameters.Expand = new string []{ "manager($select=displayName)" };
});
```

Then you can get rid of `foreach (var groupMember in groupMembers.Value)` because all users in `groupMembers` will have `Manager` filled.